Facing issue while routing and executing a build folder in nodejs
I am new to nodeJS and in my application required to add a proxy to another domain and the route should happen in root "/". When user want to login, the route need to be "domain/loginPage". so the challenge i am facing is when routing like below, its showing the issue of mimetype.
when i try without proxy Route and using "domain/loginPage" its working perfectly.
app.get('/loginPage', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build'));
});
// Proxy Middleware 
const proxyOptions = {
    target: 'http://domainName:9080/',
    changeOrigin: true,
};

const proxyGlass = createProxyMiddleware(proxyOptions);

// Proxy Route 
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.authenticated) {
        proxyGlass(req, res, next);
    } else {
        res.redirect('/loginPage');
    }
});

